# Why use SQL/NoSQL DBs over writing your own server side store?

Tags: node.js, database, redis, backend

Why use a DB like Redis over writing your own server side key: value JSON - for example?

For objectivity, let's measure value by the following metrics:

1. Flexibility
2. Speed
3. Reliability

Thinking they’re pretty case by case as is. I could structure data, through objects, sets, etc to read/write/query with more flexibility. I’m trying to learn why the feature set of these services are rich enough to warrant plugging them in per operation type i.e. user sessions, shopping cart, recommendations, product catalog, user activity logs, etc. I know, at least, some leverage memory; so, the possibility of them being more performant is nice. But, I have no concrete data yet.

Answer (score 1):

Why not build your own JSON server? For the same reason, you don't write your own operating system. It is always better to use the components which are time tested (even better if they are free).

However, there are other servers to store JSON docs in the market like CouchDB, MongoDB etc. Redis doesn't have native support for JSON, it will store JSON as serialized string.

If you need really fast read/write on complete JSON strings use Redis (fast memory based data structure cache), if you need to query parts of JSON use others JSON stores like Mongo DB etc.

Comment: I find the pitfall with SQL/NoSQL DB's is their case by case use. You say performance and reliability are strengths. Wouldn't it be more performant to write and read my own stores on the server? I suppose I'd have to log my stores well for them to be reliable, but that doesn't sound much harder. I'm thinking the flexibility I get for managing stores myself is worth it. But, it's evidently not the popular path.

Comment: Read that Redis would be faster since it ultimately runs from memory. Think I'll mark your answer as right in a couple of days, unless someone replies with comprehensive performance specs.

Comment: Awesome! I added more clarity in my question without editing it out of the context of the answer you currently have. If you happen to have suggestions to make the question, itself, more effective, I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to be more specific about your use-case but even so they would probably close it like this one https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/273127/best-strategy-for-storing-static-data-json-file-vs-db-mongo-vs-redis

Comment: Tried going for brevity. I gave more context to Mangat Rai Modi with the following reply:
"I find the pitfall with SQL/NoSQL DB's is their case by case use. You say performance and reliability are strengths. Wouldn't it be more performant to write and read my own stores on the server? I suppose I'd have to log my stores well for them to be reliable, but that doesn't sound much harder. I'm thinking the flexibility I get for managing stores myself is worth it. But, it's evidently not the popular path."

Think I should move some of that above?

Comment: That hybrid solution on the link you provided's kinda nice. Maybe this questions doomed for closure though. Think I'll just ride it out.